# Ubuntu command to return the information as displayed on whois.domaintools.com

Tags: bash, networking, ubuntu, ip

Is there some way or an ubuntu command to return most of the information (specifically, city, state, netname, netrange) like that returned when you search a particular IP in whois.domaintools.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the command `whois`, from the package `whois`?  e.g.

```
whois theonion.com
```

Comment: You will have to open up port 43 on your firewall if you have egress filtering.

Comment: thanks Mark... I am such a newbie... @rleir: thanks but it worked